# Better or logical way to echo successful notice in bash using function or variable?

Tags: bash, function, shell, logic, sh

I'm looking to echo a successful notice using function or variable.

We will be using `sleep 1` for the sake of this example. What I want to do is to print an initial notice (the title or description) and then, a successful notice when the command passed.

I've tried doing it like this:

```
function notice()
{
    if [ -z "$1" ]
    then
        echo -e "\r[OK]"   
    else
        echo -n "[  ] $1"
    fi
}

notice "This is a command"
sleep 1
notice
```

The result will show:

1. [  ] This is a command
2. Execute the command (in this case sleep 1)
3. Erase the first 3 characters and put OK in it.

I've also tried doing it another way such as showing a check mark `\u2174)` at the end but I'm not so sure if there are better ways to code/solve this problem. Shorter and cleaner codes are always appreciated.

Comment: Do you care about the actual exit status? At the moment the script will always print `[OK]` no matter what.

Comment: Yes, this was just an example hence the simple codes. It supposed to have error checking as well (in the event of failure) but what I need to know was the logic behind this problem solving. Should I use a function or variable or something else because this notice is needed as repetition and I need to call it everytime I list a few commands. I need a cleaner or shorter way to do this. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past year I've written quite a lot of bash scripts. Most of them have some kind of "notice" function which tests whether some value equals to another and prints a message on error. I think it is best to make your scripts as silent as possible, unless you really need the messages for logging purposes. I would like to give you an alternative option on the code you have.

**Your solution**

```sh
#! /bin/bash
function notice {
        if [ -z "$1" ]; then
                echo "[ ] <empty> [ ERROR ]"
        elif [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
                if [ $1 -eq "$2" ]; then
                        echo "[ OK ]"
                else
                        echo "[ FAIL ]"
                fi
        else
                echo -n "[ ] $1 "
                $1
        fi
}
notice "true"
notice $? 0
notice "false"
notice $? 0
notice
exit 0
```

**My solution**

```sh
#! /bin/bash
function message {
        local msg=$1
        local tst=$2
        local val=$3
        [ "$tst" -eq "$val" ] || echo $msg
}

true
message "error on true" $? 0
false
message "error on false" $? 0
exit 0
```

**Die solution**
If you want to abort the script immediately, you can do something like this:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
export MYPID=$$
MYEXIT=1
function error {
        exit $MYEXIT
}

function die() {
        local msg=$1
        MYEXIT=$2
        echo "$0: $msg"
        kill -s TERM "${MYPID}"
}

trap "error" TERM

true
[ $? -eq 0 ] || die "You will not see this message." 1
false
[ $? -eq 0 ] || die "Your error message here!" 2
exit 0
```

**Output**

```
# Your solution
$ ./notice.sh 
[ ] true [ OK ]
[ ] false [ FAIL ]
[ ] <empty> [ ERROR ]
$ echo $?
0

# My solution
$ ./message.sh 
error on false
$ echo $?
0

# Die solution
$ ./die.sh
./die.sh: Your error message here!
$ echo $?
2
```

P.S.
You can't really "erase" text from the screen, but you can replace it as long as you don't echo a newline to the terminal. (Note the additional white space after `[ OK ]`).

```
$ echo -ne "\rcommand is [ NOK ]"; sleep 1; echo -e "\rcommand is [ OK ] "
```

Comment: I truly appreciate your time for leaving a thorough answer with excellent examples. I've accepted it and thank you.